# Directive to remove empty and disabled fields from a form

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to hide from a form all 'lines' whose input is disabled AND empty (ie remove fields that have not be filled from a read-only form).

This is very easy with jQuery from the console :

```
$('.input-group > input:disabled').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length==0){
        $(this).parent('.input-group').remove();
    }
});
```

But this becomes tricky when I want to make a directive of it (in order to be AngularJs-compliant since my application is an angularJs one).

Basicely, every field have this (bootstrap) structure :

```
<div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon">Field Label</spanS
 <input ng-disabled="someExpression" ng-model="someModel"/>
</div>
```

So I decided to create a directive named "inputGroup" applying only on the matching class ('C') that removes the element provided its 'input' is disabled and empty.. and I could not manage to have it work since I have never been able to find some working 'disabled' attribute on the input element. There are some 'isContentEditable' and 'disabled' attributes, but they are always false, whatever the input status is....

Thus, I am still trying to understand how to do this very basic (jQuery!) thing as an AngularJs directive! Any tip welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

My current - not working ! - code (mixed with some jQuery functions since I could not find any other angular-compliant way to do it):

```
appDirectives.directive('inputGroup', function(){ 
    return { 
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(element){            
            element.children('input:disabled').each(function(){
                    if($(this).val().length == 0){
                        $(this).parent('.input-group').remove();
                    }
                });     
        } 
    } ;
});
```

**EDIT:**
It's important here to state that the model is asynchronously retrieved (through a promise), and this, I don't have it's value at the time the directive is evaluated. Thus, I guess the watch has to be on the model... but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the first argument that will be passed to your directive's linking function is `scope`, not `element`. More here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Following your method of creating a directive for `input-group`, here is a (rough) version that should do what you intend.

```
app.directive('inputGroup', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var input = element.find('INPUT'); // get a reference to the input element so we can query its attributes. 
      var inputModel = input.attr('ng-model'); // get the expression in the input's ng-model attribute
      var disabledExpression = input.attr('ng-disabled'); // get the expression in the input's ng-disabled attribute

      scope.$watch(function() {
          return scope.$eval(disabledExpression);
        }, function(value) {
        if (!scope.$eval(inputModel) && scope.$eval(disabledExpression)) {
          element.addClass('hidden');
        } else {
          element.removeClass('hidden');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And the HTML would look like this (the same as your example):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Field Label</span>
    <input ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-model="someModel" />
</div>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/UArytXOLYyJhn70UodFe?p=preview

#### removing the input

In your question you talk about actually removing the input group if empty and disabled, rather than just hiding it as in my code above. To remove rather than hide, you can replace the line `element.addClass('hidden')` with `element.remove()`, and get rid of the else clause.

Comment: Hi Michael, and thanks to this excellent tip : this looked very promisive... unfortunately, this point out another flaw here => the model is asynchronously retrieved, leading into the ng-model to be undefined at the time the directive is evaluated... I tried to do a watch on the value instead, but this didn't do the trick (scope.$watch(function() {
          return scope.$eval(inputModel);
        },...). I also tried to add an attribute with the model (...,scope :{data:=},... but the watch is only triggered once, when it's is still undefined...

Comment: Hi, okay, if I am understanding correctly, you could get around this issue by just adding an extra check to the "if" statement in the watcher, something like: 

`if (typeof scope.$eval(inputModel) !== 'undefined' && scope.$eval(inputModel) === ''  && scope.$eval(disabledExpression))`

This should prevent your `.remove()` method from running before the model data has been populated from your asyc server call.

Comment: Michael, thanks again. Unfortunately, my problem is more focused on the watch expression, I think : the watch is only triggered once, and inputModel is always undefined. I can obviously test it, but it is no more triggered... thus, I don't know for the moment what is the watchexpression that will have my watcher trigger once the model is loaded...

Comment: Ahhh, I get the problem now. Okay, so the basic problem is how to cause the watch function to be executed once the model data has loaded. I have modified the plunker to watch the model value rather than the isDisabled expression, and it seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/mEAh9pG1cs1pFtYUp3SV?p=preview (I simulate an async call taking 3 seconds to load the model data). Note that watching the model will be less efficient since it will be called each time you type in the input.

Comment: Not working by me : [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pbbpQWDfFJLNaoR5yhTm?p=preview) => the empty field should be removed, and is not

Comment: @Marvin okay, I see the problem is due to the fact that some model properties are simply not defined when the data comes from the server. In this case, the watch is not triggered. As a work-around, you could define a specific scope property to signal when the data has arrived, and watch that instead. I modified your last example:http://plnkr.co/edit/VRZ0B73bkgnxT0AxgScU?p=preview

Comment: Michael : did it eventually.... needed two tricks : add a watch expression on the disabled expression, and do the evaluation on the $parent scope. I can't show it in plnukr cause the show/hide is not working there (don't know why). Solution posted

Comment: Cool, glad you made it in the end! Best of luck with the project.